# Reference a .dll using UNC adress in Excel is blocked

Tags: dll, unc

I have written a VBA macro in Excel that references a .dll library (COM-interface) located in a UNC path (\\SERVERNAME\FOLDER).
Unfortunately my company started blocking the use of dll-files in "untrusted locations" in Office, which includes all UNC paths (using Sophos).

Is there any easy way that I can create a .dll that simply references/redirects to the original .dll?

Comment: No, you must copy the DLL locally.  And re-register it so the InprocServer32 registry key stores the local path.  Using the vendor's installer is always best.  Or do nothing, enough user complaints are useful to get IT staff to figure out what exclusions they need to make.

Comment: That's not really an option for me in this case, unfortunately. I contacted our IT staff in October last year, and they have still not even been able to understand the problem.